# How to remove < and > symbol?

Tags: php

I have a text name `@chatfun <chinu,25,M,123456>` i want to `@chatfun chinu,25,M,123456` How to replace `<` and `>` tag.

My Code :

```
<?php
  $text = '@chatfun <chinu,25,M,123456>';
  echo strip_tags($text);
?>
```

Above code i am getting the blank text. How to get my actual result?

Comment: Did you try http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) with the angular brackets in an array.

```
echo str_replace(array('>', '<'), '', $text);
```

Another option is to use regex with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace)

```
echo preg_replace("/[<>]+/", '', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `str_replace`?

```
$text = str_replace(array('<', '>'), '', '@chatfun <chinu,25,m,123456>');
```

That will replace the unwanted characters with nothing.  Only caveat is that if the characters show up anywhere else, they, too, will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting blank text because the text between the `<` and `>` is considered part of a tag.
Use `str_replace(array('<','>'),'',$text)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $to_remove = array("<",">");
  $text = '@chatfun <chinu,25,M,123456>';
  echo str_replace($to_remove,"",$text);
?>
```

[See refrence](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.str-replace.php)